Started a project on Visual Studio2022 using C++, but error 'C3861' appears on my .cpp when using Windows Biometric Framework sample code
This is the Output:
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: WindowsProject01, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>WindowsProject01.cpp
1>C:\\Users\\user\\source\\repos\\WindowsProject01 - Copy\\WindowsProject01\\WindowsProject01.cpp(43,18): error C3861: 'WinBioInitialize': identifier not found
1>C:\\Users\\user\\source\\repos\\WindowsProject01 - Copy\\WindowsProject01\\WindowsProject01.cpp(78,5): error C3861: 'WinBioUninitialize': identifier not found
1>C:\\Users\\user\\source\\repos\\WindowsProject01 - Copy\\WindowsProject01\\WindowsProject01.cpp(176,49): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>Done building project "WindowsProject01.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

I started a project of Biometrics. I am trying to use the sample code from Windows Biometric Framework to a Client Application in C++ to use my Lenovo T490 Fingerprint sensor. I already installed the Windows SDK, but after many back-and-forth on my code using Visual Studio 2022, still having errors when building it. Any leads would be appreciated.
// WindowsProject01.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.

#include "WindowsProject01.h"
#include "framework.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include <Conio.h>
#include <Stdio.h>
#include <Winbio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "Winbio.lib") // Ensure Winbio.lib is linked

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                     // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];       // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING]; // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                      _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine,
                      _In_ int nCmdShow) {
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

  // TODO: Place code here.
  // inserting begining
  // Manual Declarations
  // HRESULT WINAPI WinBioInitialize(
  //    _In_ ULONG Flags,
  //    _Reserved_ ULONG Reserved
  //);
  // Initialize Windows Biometric Framework
  HRESULT hr = WinBioInitialize(0, 0);
  if (FAILED(hr)) {
    // Handle initialization failure
    // Example: MessageBox or logging
    return FALSE;
  }

  // Initialize global strings
  LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
  LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT01, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
  MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

  // Perform application initialization:
  if (!InitInstance(hInstance, nCmdShow)) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  HACCEL hAccelTable =
      LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT01));

  MSG msg;

  // Main message loop:
  while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {
    if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg)) {
      TranslateMessage(&msg);
      DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
  }
  // Manual Declarations
  // HRESULT WINAPI WinBioUninitialize();

  // Uninitialize Windows Biometric Framework
  WinBioUninitialize();
  // inserting end
  return (int)msg.wParam;
}
//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance) {
  WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

  wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

  wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
  wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
  wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
  wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
  wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
  wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WINDOWSPROJECT01));
  wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
  wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
  wcex.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT01);
  wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
  wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

  return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow) {
  hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

  HWND hWnd =
      CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                    0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

  if (!hWnd) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
  UpdateWindow(hWnd);

  return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE: Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam,
                         LPARAM lParam) {
  switch (message) {
  case WM_COMMAND: {
    int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
    // Parse the menu selections:
    switch (wmId) {
    case IDM_ABOUT:
      DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
      break;
    case IDM_EXIT:
      DestroyWindow(hWnd);
      break;
    default:
      return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
  } break;
  case WM_PAINT: {
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
    // Draw "Biometric" text
    WCHAR szText[] = L"MITS 6400G Biometrics";
    TextOutW(hdc, 10, 10, szText, wcslen(szText));

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
  } break;
  case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
  default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
  }
  return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
  switch (message) {
  case WM_INITDIALOG:
    return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

  case WM_COMMAND:
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL) {
      EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
      return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    }
    break;
  }
  return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}


I'm not able to find any reference to WinBioInitialize in Microsoft's documentation. Where did you get that source code?

Checking this reference, there does not appear to be a WinBioInitialize() declared in WinBio.h. You can check your copy to verify this. You'll need to check where you are getting this from. Could it be from sample code and not the library?

" I am trying to use the sample code from Windows Biometric Framework..." which sample code are you talking about? Where did you get it from? Please [edit] and show the URL.
